# CREATE TABLE in Postgres locks pg_class forever

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a PostgreSQL cluster with few databases. In one of the DBs, if I try to create a new table, the command never ends until I kill the the linux proccess. I checked `pg_lock` and found that `pg_class` and the indexes on `pg_class` are locked, lock type is `relation` and mode is `RowExclusiveLock`.
I can add a column to a table but cannot create an index on a table.

If I create a table in another database, there are no locks on `pg_class`.

Every hint can help.

Here there is description of locks:

```
relname                             locktype    mode    
pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index   relation    RowExclusiveLock
pg_class_relname_nsp_index          relation    RowExclusiveLock
pg_class_oid_index                  relation    RowExclusiveLock
pg_class                            relation    RowExclusiveLock
```

Comment: Could you please show the relevant content of `pg_class` and `pg_lock`, and what exactly you are doing?  Also, there should be something in the logs, too, if the statement is waiting for longer.  Also, do you see the process in `pg_stat_activity` that holds the lock?

Comment: I ran
create table dba.arie2 (i int);

The locks are:
relname pid locktype database relation page tuple virtualxid transactionid classid objid objsubid virtualtransaction pid mode granted fastpath
pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index 24757 relation 16384 3455        5/14 24757 RowExclusiveLock TRUE TRUE
pg_class_relname_nsp_index 24757 relation 16384 2663        5/14 24757 RowExclusiveLock TRUE TRUE
pg_class_oid_index 24757 relation 16384 2662        5/14 24757 RowExclusiveLock TRUE TRUE
pg_class 24757 relation 16384 1259        5/14 24757 RowExclusiveLock TRUE TRUE

Comment: Please edit your post with these details, it is hard to parse this from the comment.

Comment: Thanks. 
I'll do it in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Normal operations don't place a persistent lock on `pg_class`.

There must be a DDL command (`CREATE TABLE`, `DROP TABLE` or similar) that is blocked because of a lock, so that it cannot complete the operation.

Check for `active` sessions in `pg_stat_activity`, their `query` and if they are hanging.

Your `CREATE TABLE` is not blocked by a table lock, but by a *row lock* in `pg_class`.

Comment: I tried to find the locking DDL, but I didn't see ant process/

Comment: You see *nothing* in `pg_locks`? You could add the results to the question, maybe that tells us something. Does the problem persist, i.e., does `CREATE TABLE` still hang?

Comment: I see only the locks on pg_class.
What do you mean by "the result". I am stuck, I don't get any results.
Thanks !

Comment: Could you look at the `pg_stat_activity` row for the hanging session and see what the wait event is?

Comment: wait_event is null.
Thanks !

Comment: If `state` is `active` and there is no wait event, then the command is running. This is surprising for a `CREATE TABLE`. Or are you using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`? Maybe add your statement to the question.